# EntityFramework: Excluding complex type from being added to table while inserting other complex type

Tags: entity-framework-4, poco

I have some POCO classes as follows:

```
public class Inquiry
    {
        public Guid InquiryID { get; set; }
        public Guid OwnerID { get; set; }
        public User Owner { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
        public decimal MaxPrice { get; set; }
        public List<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    }

public class Region
    {
        public Guid RegionID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

As can be seen, there is an association between Inquiry and Region -> Inquiry may have many Regions.
The conceptual model is as follows:
[image: conceptual model]

Regions are generally predefined values getting from a database - there are 16 regions. However, Inquiry may have 1 or more Regions.
When I try to create new enquiry (that contains 1 or more region) I get the following exception:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Region'. Cannot insert
> duplicate key in object 'dbo.Regions

Concerning database: in order to represent my association between Inquiry and region I have a table called InquiryRegions with the following columns:

- InquiryID (FK, uniqueidentitier, not null) (reference to Inquiry table)
- RegionID (FK, uniqueidentifier, not null) (reference to Region table)

What I want to do:
when new inquiry is added to the database, then instead of adding regions to table Regions, assign regions with inquiry by adding an appropriate rows to InquiryRegions table.

How can I tell EF not to add regions to the table regions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem, maybe the following solution will help someone.
First of all I had to change my InquiryRegions database table and primary key to the columns:

```
InquiryID (PK, FK, uniqueidentitier, not null) (reference to Inquiry table)
RegionID (PK, FK, uniqueidentifier, not null) (reference to Region table)
```

and then I had to explicitely tell EF that the regions already exists and there is no need to add them:

```
using(ApplicationEntities context = new ApplicationEntities)
{
   foreach(var region in inquiry.Regions)
   {
      context.Regions.Attach(region);
   }
}
```